# Python Plotly heatmap subplots - remove internal y-axis numbers and ticks

Tags: python, plot, plotly, heatmap, subplot

How do I remove the numbers and ticks from the internal y-axis in the Plot.ly heatmap subplot [graph below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpdZE.png)?  Both plots share the same y-axis range so there is no reason to show both.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


dfl = []

dfl.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,100,))))
dfl.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,100,))))


fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=len(dfl) ,print_grid=False);

for index, a in enumerate(dfl):

    sn = str(index)

    data = go.Heatmap(
            z=a.values.tolist(),
            colorscale='Viridis',
            colorbar=dict(title='units'),
        )

    fig.append_trace(data, 1, index+1)
    fig['layout']['xaxis'+str(index+1)].update(title='xaxis '+str(index))

fig['layout']['yaxis1'].update(title='y-axis')
fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=800, title='heatmap subplots')
py.iplot(fig)
```

[image: Heatmap subplots]

Answer (score 3):

Simply pass the setting 'shared_yaxes=True' to the tools.make_subplots function call, that is:

```
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=len(dfl) ,print_grid=False, shared_yaxes=True)
```

Comment: tools.make_subplots is deprecated. How would you do this with plotly now, in 2021?

Comment: @AlexLenail I added an updated answer for the newer versions of Plotly https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533935/2317426

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for newer versions of Plotly.  Based upon the [v4 migration guide](https://plotly.com/python/v4-migration/).

Differences include

- calling the `make_subplots` function from the `plotly.subplots` library, instead of `plotly.tools`, and
- using `fig.show` inplace of `py.iplot` to show the figure in Jupyter.

The code below was tested in Plotly version 5.1.0 using Jupyter Notebook.

```
import plotly

import plotly.graph_objs as go

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


dfl = []

dfl.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,100,))))
dfl.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,100,))))


fig =  plotly.subplots.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=len(dfl) ,print_grid=False, shared_yaxes=True);

for index, a in enumerate(dfl):

    sn = str(index)

    data = go.Heatmap(
            z=a.values.tolist(),
            colorscale='Viridis',
            colorbar=dict(title='units'),
        )

    fig.append_trace(data, 1, index+1)
    fig['layout']['xaxis'+str(index+1)].update(title='xaxis '+str(index))

fig['layout']['yaxis1'].update(title='y-axis')
fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=800, title='heatmap subplots')
fig.show()
```

The output:

[image: plotly_v5_output]